# WSL ubuntu docker installation error. with `unix:///var/run/docker.sock.` message

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed docker with the following command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

But when I run docker ps, I get the following error:

```
XXXXX@DESKTOP-XXXXX:~$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run Docker on WSL directly (you don't have the same kernel capabilities that you have with Linux distros).

You can run Docker in HyperV and configure you Docker client in WSL to connect to it: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly

Or start experimenting with WSL 2 Docker backend (it's not that mature, probably has a lot more limitations and bugs): https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/

Answer (score 0):

You should start the docker service, for Debian distro you can run the command:

```
sudo service docker start
```

or run the `docked` command